# What kind of construction is 覚まさんとしていた?

Tags: grammar

I have the following sentence I'm trying to translate:
暗く打ち寄せる波の下には、血に飢えた神々が目を**覚まさんとしていた**……。
I tried translating the sentence as follows:
Surging from the dark waves, bloodthirsty gods **were trying to awaken**.
I'm not entirely sure if my translation suffices, so I would appreciate any help regarding that, however, my main concern is the way the verb 覚ます is conjugated, I had never seen such a construction. Is it translated as *to try to* or something similar? and what is it called?

Comment: I think your translation is pretty good.  I'm going to hold off on answering this because, while I feel comfortable reading this sort of grammar, I'm not 100% sure how or why it works the way it does.

Comment: As the previous answer says, perhaps a more natural translation would be "gods were *about to* awaken."